# MySQL show all records based on id

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to show which users liked a specific post.

The code is as follows:

```
$getlikes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post_id = $id");
                        $likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getlikes);
                        $liked_users = $likes_row['user_id'];
```

This would output only one user while 2 users liked the post.

The MySQL DB table is as follows:

`id | user_id | post_id`

`1  | someone | 1`

`2  | bob     | 1`

They both liked post 1 but it only shows `someone`.

I'd like both of them to show up, for example:

`Someone and Bob liked this post`

Comment: That's because you fetch only one line. See [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) doc (example 2).

Comment: What is  the o/p for `var_dump($liked_users)`...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @tadman I've got it covered, but thanks for the heads up ^_^

Comment: Doesn't look like it in your example there. Seeing things like `$id` in the query is usually a gigantic red flag and an automatic fail on any code review. Just looking out for you.

Comment: @tadman Thanks! Much appreciated, but like you said, it's just an example. The original file has it covered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$getlikes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post_id = $id");
while ( $likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getlikes))
$liked_users[] = $likes_row['user_id'];
```

and if you like `echo` so much you can `echo` this way:

```
$getlikes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post_id = $id");
while ( $likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getlikes))
echo $likes_row['user_id'];
```

I am really surprising of how much you like echo and don't like arrays, so just for you,
here is third variant how to use your query, the most strange one:

```
$liked_users='';
$getlikes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post_id = $id");
while ( $likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getlikes))
$liked_users.= ($liked_users=='')?$likes_row['user_id']:', '.$likes_row['user_id'];

echo $liked_users;
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, it only posts `Array`

Comment: posts??? there is no post, just variable... so show what are doing with that variable :-)

Comment: I tried using `$getlikes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE post_id = $id");
      while ( $likes_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getlikes)) {
       $liked_users[] = $likes_row['user_id'];
      }`                                                                                          So I'm using echo to show `$liked_users` which gives me `Array`

Comment: because you can't echo an array :-) do `print_r($liked_users)` or `var_dump($liked_users)`

Comment: Hmm, that gives me `array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "someone" [1]=> string(12) "bob" }`

Comment: really? but what did you expect? :-)

Comment: I wanted to show just the two users. So `Someone and Bob` instead of that array

Comment: that means you don't use MY CODE :-)

Comment: I copied your code and tried it. It did not work for me.

Comment: @BroskyaP you are saying the code in the question is "just an example". Maybe if we had the original code we could do something better for you. Alex's suggestion works well with the example you gave, please show what you have now.

Comment: @BroskyaP try to allow the thought that you are just lied to me. and check the code you use twice. and/or add new code in your post. so everybody  can see it.

Comment: @Alex, first of all, I did not lie to you, I did copy your code and used it. It now works for me. The only thing I can't do is post it on a different location on the page, for example: `$user_likes = $likes_row['user_id'];` And Somewhere else put `echo $user_likes`

Comment: no you did lie. and that is absolutely okay for me. because if you didn't lie previous time - you are liing now? because in both cases you said you had used my code, but in one case it doesn't work, and in another it works. so that is clear that in one of those cases you did not use my code. and the reason why you cant echo 2 or 3 or 100 names somewhere on your page is because you don't know how to use `array` type variables. so just go and google that. or... check my update :-)